# .htaccess rewriting suddenly adding .php instead of removing it

Tags: php, .htaccess, url-rewriting

I have a htaccess file with this contents:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteRule ^/?([a-z]+)?$ $1.php [NC]
RewriteRule ^account/([0-9a-zA-Z]+) account.php?$1 [NC,L]
```

it's working and is properly rewriting my urls https://example.com/account.php to https://example.com/account/

also $_GET parameters work: 
https://example.com/account/settings/ but the strange thing is, that if I try to access https://example.com/account/servers/ it is rewriting it to https://example.com/account/servers.php/ 
It's only for the "servers" parameter for no other

Comment: are there any other rules?

Comment: Nope. There aren't any

Comment: Do you have a real file under /accounts or is /accounts a real directory?

Comment: No it isn't. Account is a php file itself. I mean it's rewriting it to servers.php/ but the page does still work as the parameter is still working. It's just about how it looks